# C# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods for void

Tags: c#, namespaces

This is my code im trying to make a stop, pause and start button and im fairly new to programming but the void bit is giving me an error, A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

```
void MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (musicPlayer.CurrentState)
    {
        case MediaElementState.Playing:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Paused:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Stopped:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
            break;
        case MediaElementState.Closed:
            systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

}

Comment: Post the rest of the code

Comment: The code itself looks fine, it's where it's located that's the error message - all methods have to be inside a class, but (apparently) this code isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably lacking a class and is writing the method directly in the namespace.

Comment: Or OP would have closed the class definition using `}` by mistake :)